# How to make the Glossy material in Blender not too dark?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials

I was making a 3D eye and when I added a glossy material to the model, the light looks great, except for the fact that the model looks too dark. Is there any way to fix it? Maybe add a better material setup for it? (I need a fast/quick material, not a complex one, I have very little time)

[image]

Comment: Try adding a diffuse shader as well. And double check your lighting.

Comment: Make sure the color of the glossy is white.

Comment: @VinceScalia Go ahead and add as an answer for the answer ratio

Comment: oookat. answering

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise If he adds the answer UV.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a *Diffuse* shader to your material. The color of a *Glossy* shader is influenced by what is being reflected, so having a *Diffuse* shader underneath will make the color more consistent across the entire mesh, in all settings.

[image]

With a 100% white input, here were my results:

**Just Glossy:**

[image]

**With Diffuse:**

[image]

Comment: True, but he might just wan't his mesh to be that reflective, in which case this may not work... But it is nice to avoid having to create/find an HDR.

Comment: Most objects are not 100% reflective anyways I have noticed. No matter what lighting, you can always tell the color of it. Especially something complex and organic like an eye.

Comment: I agree he should add a diffuse texture, but It is useful to have any degree of reflectiveness visible, which is more what the question is.

Comment: True. I agree with that.

Answer (score 13):

You need the change your background. It is currently reflecting the sky, wich is that dark grey color. I would recommend adding an [HDR image](http://giantcowfilms.com/category/hdrs/) To add reflections etc.

**Without HDR:**

[image]

**With HDR:**

[image]

No lights or materials were changed in the setup.

**Adding A HDR Background:**

[image]

Set the works "color" to environment texture. You may need to raise the strength to make it bright enough.

You can still have the grey background with a little hack if you need it:

Simply add these nodes to your world material.

[image]

**Not-Ideal HDR work around**
In the case you don't have an HDR, you can use this workaround. The reflections will be less realistic, but it still works well.

Add these nodes to your world material:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the color of the glossy shader is set to white, either with an external color node (as seen in @NoviceInDisguise's answer), or with the color setting in the glossy node itself.

[image]